# Ember promise not resolved when I expect it to be

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a custom component that expects data and not a promise, but I am unsure if they way that I am obtaining the data is the right way.

Is this the right way to do it?

#### component hbs

```
{{x-dropdown content=salutations valuePath="id" labelPath="description" action="selectSalutation"}}
```

## Doesn't work

#### controller (this is the way I expect things to work

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  bindSalutations: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.store.find('salutation').then(function(data) {
      self.set('salutations', data);
    });
  }.on('init'),
```

#### components/x-dropdown.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  list: function() {
    var content   = this.get('content');
    var valuePath = this.get('valuePath');
    var labelPath = this.get('labelPath');

    return content.map(function(item) {
      return {
        key:   item[labelPath],
        value: item[valuePath],
      };
    });
  }.property('content'),
```

## This works

#### controller

```
bindSalutations: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.store.find('salutation').then(function(data) {
    self.set('salutations', data.get('content'));   // pass the content instead of just the data
  });
}.on('init'),
```

#### component

```
...

  list: function() {
    var content   = this.get('content');
    var valuePath = this.get('valuePath');
    var labelPath = this.get('labelPath');

    return content.map(function(item) {
      return {
        key:   item._data[labelPath],     // access through the _data attribute
        value: item._data[valuePath],
      };
    });
  }.property('content'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data returns a Proxy Promise.  This means you can use the promise as if it were a collection or model itself, as long as you aren't dependent on the property being completely populated when you use it.  If you really want the promise resolved, you should probably be setting it up in the route.

If you want it on your controller, you can be lazy and do it like so:

#### Controller

```
salutations: function() {
  this.store.find('salutation');
}.property(),
```

#### Component

```
...

  list: function() {
    var content   = this.get('content'),
        valuePath = this.get('valuePath'),
        labelPath = this.get('labelPath');

    return content.map(function(item) {
      return {
        key:   item.get(labelPath), 
        value: item.get(valuePath),
      };
    });
  }.property('content.[]'),
```

#### Template

```
{{x-dropdown content=salutations valuePath="id" labelPath="description" action="selectSalutation"}}
```

The real trick is to watch if the collection is changing.  Hence you'll see I changed the property argument to `content.[]`